# Date conversion and range check in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to convert text column `ITM_DTE` into date type in table `tblCS_ITM` and validate the range in that column. I tried to run the following query, but it's giving `data type mismatch` error

```
SELECT tblCS_ITM.*
FROM tblCS_ITM
WHERE #01-01-2013#  < CDate(Format("dd-mm-yyyy",[ITM_DTE]));
```

`ITM_DTE` column data as follows

```
30-05-2012
16-07-2012
05-02-2012
15-05-2013
```

What can be the issue

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format() expects an expression first and then a format specification, not the other way around. For example, see [Format Function - Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) and [MS Access: Format Function (with Dates)](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)

Try the following:

```
SELECT tblCS_ITM.*
FROM tblCS_ITM
WHERE #01/01/2013# < CDate(Format([ITM_DTE],"dd-mm-yyyy"));
```